# Rails 3 validate URL or IP address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, url

I'm searching for a way to validate a field for correct URL or IP address in a rails model. I've played a little bit with `validates :url, :format => URI::regexp(%w(http https))`, and other URL validations. But how do I get the field validated with either an URL or an IP address? Maybe there is a gem for that.

thx!

Comment: So the valid field can be `http://host.tld` as well as `127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: exactly, both methods should be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there are such gems, but custom validations can be implemented relatively simple (with [`ipaddress`](https://github.com/bluemonk/ipaddress) gem in the Gemfile). Try something like

```
require 'uri'
validate :valid_url_or_ip
...
private
def valid_url_or_ip
  unless valid_url?(url) || IPAddress.valid?(url)
    errors.add(:url, "Not an URL or IP address")
  end
end

def valid_url?
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  uri.kind_of?(URI::HTTP) || uri.kind_of?(URI::HTTPS)
rescue URI::InvalidURIError
  false
end
```